# gql error: BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid ORDER BY Property at symbol :3

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I'm getting this error:

```
Parse Error: Invalid ORDER BY Property at symbol :3
```

Can't see what is causing it, if I remove the substitution and add "date" it works.

```
order = "date"
playlists_data = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Playlist WHERE 
                              client = :1 AND 
                              category = :2 
                              ORDER BY :3 DESC', client, category, order)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORDER BY doesn't support bound parameters.

They can only be used in a WHERE clause, and only to replace property values, not property names.